# Asp.Net VNext Windows service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core

I want to try moving to VNext from Asp.Net MVC 3, I used windows service project (http://www.interworks.com/blogs/banderton/2009/10/30/long-running-tasks-aspnet) but this doesn't seem to work on VNext, because it doesn't have proper `System.ServiceModel` reference and I cant add dll.
Is there a way around? Would you recommend other ways to run long tasks such as big file import/calculations with VNext?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no - not because of any feature-set in ASP.NET vNext (it's been possible since .NET 1.0) but because of permissions: a process needs to run under a high-privilege security context or be able to impersonate such a user account in order to control Windows Services.

`w3wp.exe` (the application pool hosting process, and by extension, the application pool and the applications within it) all typically run under a least-privilege user-account (often `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` or a custom user account with enough permissions to write to the website's root directory, a database server, and not much else (in recent versions of Windows this is further reduced to the concept of a "service account" which your worker-process and pools run under).

The easiest solution is to create a user-account with the necessary privileges to control services and run your application pool process under this user-account, but I don't recommend this.

Consider, instead, creating a new Windows Service that then controls the other service (or if it's your own service, do it in-proc) that uses some form of IPC to communicate with your ASP.NET application to shut itself down and perform other tasks. You might want to look at named-pipes, for example.

Comment: Would you recommend anything specific? I would love to use this http://www.interworks.com/blogs/banderton/2009/10/30/long-running-tasks-aspnet but vnext doesnt have proper System.ServiceModel lib, and I cant add dll reference

Comment: @user007 `System.ServiceModel` is WCF (`System.ServiceProcess` is Windows Service). The article you linked to is about developing a WCF service that runs within a Windows Service. .NET still includes `System.ServiceModel.dll` - you're probably looking in the wrong place.

Comment: One problem is that I cant add my library to vnext from the c# library project which holds IJobService interface, another problem is that System.ServiceModel reference is missing in vnext. I tried using nuget to find it, added it to reference, but the problem is the same http://s10.postimg.org/56n8xg0zt/Captursssse.png I guess at this stage vnext doesnt support references from dll and maybe later it will be implemented?

Comment: @user007 how on earth are you able to add a reference to .NET 1.0?!!

Comment: There is no other version for VNext in nuget, only v1 http://s30.postimg.org/jgktlwh8x/Captursssse.png and I am able to install it but it doesnt do much...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run ASP.NET in a Windows service, you can do it now using ASP.NET 5. I wrote a detailed post on how to do this here: http://taskmatics.com/blog/host-asp-net-in-a-windows-service/